# Resources to Move to WPF and C# with a C++ Background

Tags: c#, wpf

My colleague is moving to WPF development in C# from a C++ background. I'm collecting resources that will help get up to speed. The ones I've found so far are these:

C#:

- [What You Need to Know to Move from C++ to C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx)
- [C# for C++ Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) articles

WPF:

- [Getting Started with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119.aspx) articles

All of the above are from MSDN. Could anyone suggest some other relevant material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some WPF articles:

- [10 things Beginning Silverlight and WPF Developers Need to Know](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/08/26/10-things-beginning-silverlight-and-wpf-developers-need-to-know)
- [Fun With Physics](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PhysicsFun.aspx)
- [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Home.html)